# Github structuring for release cycles

Tags: node.js, git, express, github, webhooks

I'm reasonably new to using Github and I don't think I'm trying to do the simplest thing so I could really do with some help. I think I'm almost there.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

1. I create a prerelease of my repo
2. Github sends webhook request notifying my server
3. My server sees it's a prerelease, clones the repo and checks out the prerelease to a live test environment
4. Whilst that's being tested, I continue working and making commits
5. When the test team is happy with the prerelease, I go back and make it a full release

Here's how my Node Express server receives the webhook:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){ 

  //event is not a release
  if (req.headers["x-github-event"] != "release") return;

  //push release to test or live server
  else if (req.body.release.prerelease) pushToDev(req);
  else if (!req.body.release.prerelease) pushToLive(req);

});
```

Everything for doing a prerelease is working fine. I'm just not sure about a couple of things:

1. How would I make a release from the same date as the prerelease after testing is complete? This would then push that version to my live server.
2. Is this a bad structure generally? Do I need to be using branches? I haven't really go my head around that yet so any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should consider using branches - this is a common scenario, and there are some good solutions for this.

Atlassian has a pretty good overview of possible workflows [here, comparing different branching workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows).

A popular workflow is [Git-Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), also described [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).

With Git-Flow, you work on a `develop` branch and feature branches to do your work. All of your releases are done from release branches and then merged into the `master` branch.

So in your case, your prerelease could be done in a release branch (or even in master), while you continue to work in `develop` to make additional changes. Once the prerelease has been tested, you can create a real release from that branch.